# Derivative of a fraction with summation

Tags: derivatives, summation, fractions, chain-rule

I have to find the derivative of ${r(x) = \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{w_i}{x-x_i}f_i}{\sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{w_i}{x-xi}}}$. I know I have to use the chain rule, but I don't know how to apply it in this case (how many functions do we have?), and in addition I don't how how to compute the derivative of this kind of summation.

Comment: As an example, try $n=3$ by expanding the sums. And then using the quotient rule once for the $\frac {summation} {summation}$ and each time for the $\frac {w_i} {x-x_i}$.  I know, it's a bit long, but you should see rather easily how this extends when $n$ is any integer.

Comment: @BernardMasse by the chain rule, I have to apply the derivative of ${\frac{summation}{summation}}$, multiplied by the derivative of the nominator multiplied by the derivative of the denominator?

Answer (score 1):

It could be simpler using the logarithmic derivative
$${r(x) = \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{w_i}{x-x_i}f_i}{\sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{w_i}{x-xi}}}\quad \implies \quad \log[r(x)]=\log\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{w_i}{x-x_i}f_i\right)-\log\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{w_i}{x-xi} \right)$$
$$\frac{r'(x)}{r(x)}=-\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{w_i}{(x-x_i)^2}f_i}  {\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{w_i}{x-x_i}f_i}+\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{w_i}{(x-x_i)^2}}  {\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{w_i}{x-x_i}}$$

Now, use
$$r'(x)=r(x) \times \frac{r'(x)}{r(x)}$$ and simplify.